ZoneJS: How to set a timeout for a macrotask?
I use Angular SSR. I created this service with code largely from the internet. Its purpose is that on the server side, Angular will wait for a specified async operation to finish, before it sends back the rendered HTML to the user. For example, a DB request to get info about a user.

Service:
export class WaitForService {
    private taskId = 0;

    waitFor<T>(promise: Promise<T> | Observable<T>) { 
        if (isObservable(promise)) { 
            promise = firstValueFrom(promise);
        }
        const macrotaskName = WAITFOR-${this.taskId++}
        const macroTask = Zone.current.scheduleMacroTask(
            macrotaskName, () => {}, {}, () => {}
        )
        promise.finally(() => macroTask.invoke())
    }
}

Usage:
MyComponent:
constructor(...) {
    if (isServerSide) {
        this.waitForService.waitFor(this.myAsyncFunction());
    }
}


This approach works but there is one major issue. I need to set a timeout. If for some reason the DB request takes very long, the server will be in a "not-responding" state for the end user. So I want to say: If it exceeds 2 seconds for example, skip the async operation and just return the HTML.
My attempt was adopting the code like this:
const macroTask = Zone.current.scheduleMacroTask(
    macrotaskName, 
    () => {}, {}, () => {}
)

// time out
const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { 
    macroTask.invoke() 
}, TIMEOUT_AFTER_MS)

promise.finally(() => {
    macroTask.invoke()
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
})

So simply adding a timeout which will invoke the macro task if not canceled. But this doesn't work. The result remains the same and the server still waits for the async operation to finish.
I don't know why. I've tried many different things over the past few days but they all don't work.

My understanding of this process is the following. Much of this info comes from LLMs because I didnt find anything in the docs about how to make angular ssr wait.

Angular SSR (the express server) will wait for the app to be stable before sending the HTML back

An angular app is stable if the angular zone is stable

A zone is stable if there are no micro or macro tasks on the task queue

By using schedule macrostask we tell the current zone (should be the angular zone) that there is a task waiting, so the app is unstable

When later calling invoke() we let that task run, but since its empty, it finishes immediately, so the app becomes stable again

Now the server side part finishes and the HTML is sent to the end user.


Is this correct? If so, why does my attempt for timeout functionality not work? How to make it work?
I'm also open for other approaches for making the Angular SSR server wait for an async operation. But this was the only approach I could find on the internet that worked.
